# How to solve the zkemkeeper problem?

Tags: c#

I have used zkemkeeper dll to access the attendance record of finger print device.As suggested by sdk, i have used ReadGeneralLogData(MachineNumber) to read the data to memory and GetGeneralLogData(MachineNo,enrollmentNo,...) to read the data from memory to PC. But i am getting invalid data like it always gives attendance year as 2000 and random enrollment number etc. So, how to solve this problem.Please help me. I am using c# in vs2010.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks Jig for your answer and i solve this problem myself. I have found that the machine which i have used is TFT(determines attendance machine is Finger print machine or not) so before using GetGeneralLogData(MachineNo,enrollmentNo,...) API i have to checked whether it is TFT or not, if it is TFT then i have to use SSR_GetGeneralLogData() instead of another one.

Answer (score 1):

- First Check machine DateTime and set time synchronize with Server machine
- May be u get buffer data or old data
- how to fetch records from database or direct machine ?

How to fetch records u note down some hint or codes where u may be write wrong code